# nsis - customize button text on MessageBox

Tags: customization, nsis, messagebox

I need to customize the buttons' labels on MessageBox MB_YESNOCANCEL. E.g. instead of 'Cancel' I need to have 'Resign' label. Does anybody know how it can be done?

Comment: Hello.. can you provide me example of custom plugin for customize button text on message box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done without writing a custom plugin...